# How would you word the sentence "if you cancel in the three days before the tour date, all application fee is on your charge"?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

How would you word the sentence "if you cancel in the three days before the tour date, all application fee is on your charge"?

I want to say that if you do not cancel the tour date 4 days before the date, you will still be charged.

Comment: Your application fee becomes nonrefundable three days before the tour date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can say this, let's break it into two parts:

> If you cancel in the three days before the tour date *(awkward)*

This part is correct English, and understandable, but slightly awkward.  A more common way to say this would be something like:

> **If you cancel within three days of the tour date**

(Technically, "within three days" could mean three days before or three days after, but from the context it's obvious that we're talking about before here (nobody expects to get their money back after the date of an event))

If you want a slightly more formal feel, you can put the sentence in the passive tense:

> **If the reservation is cancelled within three days of the tour date**

As for the second part:

> all application fee is on your charge *(strange)*

Somebody would probably be able to figure out what you mean, but this sounds decidedly strange and a bit confusing.  Actually, the way you put it in your later explanation is much better:

> you will still be charged *(good)*

If you want to be a little bit more specific you could say:

> **you will still be charged the application fee**

Or, as above, if you want a slightly more formal way to say the same thing, you can phrase it in the passive tense:

> **the application fee will still be charged**

Though this does somewhat imply that you haven't already charged them for it, which if it's an application fee I'd assume you probably do up front, so possibly a better way to express this would be to say instead that they won't get their money back (refunded):

> **the application fee will not be refunded**

So, putting them together, I would recommend something like either:

> **If you cancel within three days of the tour date, you will still be charged the application fee.**

(which is relatively informal/friendly but still businesslike and quite clear)

or

> **If the reservation is cancelled within three days of the tour date, the application fee will not be refunded.**

(which has a much more formal feel to it, but that also does make it sound a bit harsher (like a lawyer or corporation is saying it))